# Keyboard LED panel indicator for Unity Desktop

Tags: unity, keyboard, indicator, capslock, numlock

I own a notebook running Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity DE that does not have any keyboard LEDs to indicate NUM-Lock or CAPS-Lock states.

It would be useful for me to see them anyway, ideally through an indicator in Unity's panel.

Please note that I only want to see the states of NUM-Lock, CAPS-Lock and optionally Scroll-Lock. I do *not* want to see whether any other modifier keys like Shift, Ctrl, Alt, Super etc. are currently pressed. I only want a replacement for my missing LEDs.

Are there any working indicators available?

---

I already have read [How to add a keyboard modifier state applet to Unity panel?](https://askubuntu.com/q/402315/367990), but it does not suit my needs. `indicator-xkbmod` only displays a wrong icon but does not react on keyboard NUM-/CAPS-Lock status changes, `kbstate` is for KDE only and `key-mon` does not show the NUM-/CAPS-Lock states but indicates key presses to modifier keys.

Comment: If you can find a terminal command(s) that will give you the status of CAPS/NUM/SCROLL lock, you could install `indicator-sysmonitor` and add custom script which obtains the status information (using the aformentioned terminal command(s)). Refer to [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/501365/67335) and follow the trail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also written an application indicator which, in my opinion, looks better.

### [indicator-keyboard-led](https://github.com/adrianiainlam/indicator-keyboard-led)

It shows the state of the locks using filled/unfilled circles.

[image: indicator default]
Default appearance of the indicator with Num lock on and Caps and Scroll locks
off.

[image: indicator menu]
Menu of the indicator, shown on click. The locks can be toggled by clicking
the respective item in the menu.

[image: indicator short]
Alternative (short) appearance of the indicator.

[image: indicator CNS] [image: indicator NC] [image: indicator C short]
You can also change which locks are displayed and in what order.

#### Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adrianiainlam/indicator-keyboard-led
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-keyboard-led
```

After installation the postinst script will prompt you for preferences configuration. Visit the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/adrianiainlam/indicator-keyboard-led) for full explanation on these settings.

#### Usage:

The indicator will be configured to autostart on log-in. To start using the indicator after installation, log-out and log-in again, or manually start the indicator (search for "indicator-keyboard-led" in the dash).

The indicator should be shown at the top right corner, with a filled circle representing a lock turned on and an unfilled circle representing a lock turned off.

Clicking on the indicator should result in a menu with the three locks. Clicking on the menu item would cause the corresponding lock to toggle.

<sub>Bug reports and feature requests welcome.</sub>

Comment: Looks great, will test it soon.

Comment: Cool thing. However, I have two feature requests: 1) Could you please add a "Quit" menu entry to your indicator, and 2) could you please add an option (e.g. command-line parameter) that allows to hide all Scroll Lock related stuff as this seems not to be supported correctly by Ubuntu... Thanks!

Comment: @ByteCommander Done and done. See edited post (or README).

Comment: @ace - This doesn't work anymore on Ubuntu 17.04. Only the lock icon appears. The icons for Caps, Num, etc. doesn't appear.

Comment: @Raphael No repro on a Live CD. [(Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCdd5.png). If it still doesn't work then perhaps you can try something similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/922825/274080)? Also please try running it from a terminal and see if any errors or warnings show up.

Answer (score 7):

#### Introduction

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of this indicator

The `lks-indicator` allows showing the status of all the lock keys , such as Caps, Num, and Scroll lock. By default it shows green icon when no keys are engaged, and switches to red if one or more is engaged, while also showing text representation of which key is active.

#### Usage:

As shown by `-h` option:

```
usage: lks-indicator [-h] [--show-all] [-m]
                     [--ignore-keys IGNORE_KEYS [IGNORE_KEYS ...]]

lks-indicator - Indicates on/off status of Lock keys.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --show-all            Show all keys in label
  -m, --monochrome      Use monochrome icon
  --ignore-keys IGNORE_KEYS [IGNORE_KEYS ...]
                        Ignore specified keys (C, N or S)
```

Starting the indicator via command line is simple:

```
python lks-indicator
```

Users can specify which keys to ignore , with multiple keys separated by spaces. For example,

```
python lks-indicator --ignore-keys N S
```

By default , indicator only shows text representation of keys when they are engaged. If you want to always show them use `--show-all` option.

[image]

Please use, `Quit` button to close the indicator, as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut via command line doesn't work well with app-indicators

The indicator by default works with color icons, red and green, but there's also `-m` option to use monochrome icon.

[image]

#### Installation

**git approach**

For those who have `git` installed:

1. `cd /opt`
2. `sudo git clone https://github.com/SergKolo/lks-indicator.git`
3. `chmod -R +x /opt/lks-indicator/`

`git` will also allow keeping it updated easily with `cd /opt/lks-indicator ; git pull` , so I strongly recommend using this method.

**Zip package approach**:

Alternatively, you can download [zip package](https://github.com/SergKolo/lks-indicator/archive/master.zip) and extract it where you see fit. Debian package is also available in the repository.

To make it start on every login into Unity , please consult this post: [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/295286)

**Gnome Users** : you will need [AppIndicator Support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) installed , and optionally Gnome Tweak Tool. Otherwise the bracketed text wont be displayed, only red/green icon.

The indicator also has been tested in MATE and Ubuntu Kylin.

Comment: Nice, but can you make the output a bit more clear? I would like something like e.g. `N C S` for all off and `[N] [C] [S]` for all on.

Comment: @ByteCommander Will be done.  It's a simple task of parsing text. Will ping you once I have updated version

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - This doesn't work anymore on Ubuntu 17.04. Only the monochrome or red icon appears. The icons for Caps, Num, etc. doesn't appear.

Comment: @Raphael  You have to start the indicator with command-line switches to see the letters for keys. Did you try that ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - This is what I used: `lks-indicator --show-all -m`

Comment: @Raphael  OK,  I'll have to get  17.04 virtual machine and check it, because it works fine for me.  Are you using GNOME by any chance or other desktop environment ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - Yes, `i3` with tray icons enabled and `py3status` on XUbuntu.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - Also, it doesn't work in `xfce4-panel`

Comment: @Raphael   Does it throw any error messages when you run in terminal ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - No error messages

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - Were you able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Raphael I haven't obtained 17.10iso yet.  I can't reproduce it on my 16.04 Ubuntu.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - Ok. Also, I have seen that this issue has been reported once in your github page.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use indicator-keylock, it's one the first apps I install when I setup my Ubuntu system.
It is included in ubuntu oficial repos for quite some time, works great and looks pretty.

To install, simply:
`sudo apt install indicator-keylock`