# How can I get a numlock notification like the volume notification in Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, numlock

In GNOME 3 the audio change notification looks like this:

[image]

Can I get a caps lock or num lock icon like it?

Comment: You could check out the answers to [my old question here](https://askubuntu.com/q/796985/367990) for ideas on how to detect Num-Lock state changes. Then it should be easy to write a custom script that displays a notification.

Comment: @ByteCommander the issue is how to display the notification. I don't know how gnome does it.

Comment: Me neither. Maybe you could just try a `notif-send "Num-Lock is ON"` or similar as a start? Don't know how these get displayed on Gnome.

Comment: @ByteCommander same as unity. That's easy and there are extensions for it but I really want it like the volume one.

Answer (score 3):

To display a notification like the volume one in Gnome 3 you can use `gdbus` (`dbus-send` won't work because it can't pass function parameters of type `a{sv}` *(array of dict{string:variant}*))

With `gdbus` the volume notification looks like this:

```
gdbus call --session --dest 'org.gnome.Shell' --object-path '/org/gnome/Shell' --method 'org.gnome.Shell.ShowOSD' "{'icon': <'audio-volume-high-symbolic'>, 'label': <'Line-Out'>, 'level': <90>}"
```

So for something like Numlock on notification you'd use:

```
gdbus call --session --dest 'org.gnome.Shell' --object-path '/org/gnome/Shell' --method 'org.gnome.Shell.ShowOSD' "{'icon': <'input-dialpad-symbolic'>, 'label': <'Numlock On'>}"
```

Icon names are the names of the icon files from the icon theme in use without the extension. Icons themes are located in `/usr/share/icons/` or `~/.icons/`. So for the `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/devices/input-dialpad-symbolic.svg` you'd use `'input-dialpad-symbolic'`. You can also specify icon by it's full path like `'/home/user/.icons/Icon-Theme-Name/devices/symbolic/input-dialpad-symbolic.svg'` if it's not in the icon theme in use.

*The way I discovered this is by looking at dbus calls by using `dbus-monitor`. When I lowered the volume it printed this:*

```
method call time=1563905341.664155 sender=:1.34 -> destination=:1.8 serial=149 path=/org/gnome/Shell; interface=org.gnome.Shell; member=ShowOSD
array [
  dict entry(
     string "icon"
     variant             string "audio-volume-high-symbolic"
  )
  dict entry(
     string "label"
     variant             string "Line Out"
  )
  dict entry(
     string "level"
     variant             int32 94
  )
]
```

*`destination=:1.8` seems to be the same as `org.gnome.Shell` so both `--dest ':1.8'` and `--dest 'org.gnome.Shell'` work.*

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! **:-)** Great first answer!  **+1**