# Unknown Tray Icon Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: icons, system-tray, taskbar, budgie

Okay so I have searched everything I can think of but I cannot figure out what this icon/app is:

[image: mysterious icon]

As you can see I've right clicked on the icon and all I receive is that empty grey box. Any insight would be greatly appreciated; if you need any specific logs to narrow down the options let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have DropBox installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for Dropbox and Skype icons in 17.04 are the same...

Reference: http://www.webupd8.org/2017/04/fix-appindicator-not-working-for.html

[Quick update] It looks like Dropbox isn't the only AppIndicator that doesn't work in Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zapus (under Unity) due to the change of XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP from "Unity" to "Unity:Unity7".

Electron applications (such as the new Skype For Linux, WMail, PB For Desktop and many others) are affected as well, but in a different way. For Electron applications, the indicator is not displayed at all in Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zapus under Unity.

The fix is similar to the one applied to the Dropbox indicator. Simply run the application with "env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity". For example, to start Skype For Linux, you would use:

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity skypeforlinux
```

To make the fix permanent, copy the application desktop file from /usr/share/applications/ to ~/.local/share/applications/, then edit the file and change the "Exec" line by adding "**env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity**" (without the quotes) immediately after "Exec=".

Some applications are set to start automatically and in that case, you'll have to edit the desktop file from ~/.config/autostart/ in the same way.

Note that some applications overwrite any changes made to their autostart files, located in ~/.config/autostart/. A way around this is to rename the autostart file, then in the application settings, set the application not to start on login. This way, the modified autostart file will be used (which has a different name and contains the workaround).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments to the OP, @Terrance correctly identified the rogue icon as a glitched out Dropbox. I have restored my icon to full functionality by following the answer here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/739018/697453

I am on Ubuntu Budgie 17.04 and the solution worked for me!